# Missing value replacemnet using mode in pandas in subgroup of a group

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Having a data set as below.Here I need to group the subset in column and fill the missing values using mode method.Here specifically needs to fill the missing value of Tom from UK. So I need to group the TOM from Uk, and in that group the most repeating value needs to be added to the missing value.

[image: datammain]

Below fig shows how i need to do the group by.From the below matrix i need to replace all the Nan values using mode.

[image: new]

the desired output:

[image: output]

attaching the dataset

```
Name location Value
Tom  USA      20
Tom  UK       Nan
Tom  USA      Nan
Tom  UK       20
Jack India    Nan
Nihal Africa  30
Tom   UK      Nan
Tom   UK      20
Tom   UK      30
Tom   UK      20
Tom   UK      30
Sam   UK      30
Sam   UK      30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
df = df\
    .set_index(['Name', 'location'])\
    .fillna(
        df[df.Name.eq('Tom') & df.location.eq('UK')]\
            .groupby(['Name', 'location'])\
            .agg(pd.Series.mode)\
            .to_dict()
    )\
    .reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
     Name location Value
0     Tom      USA    20
1     Tom       UK    20
2     Tom      USA   NaN
3     Tom       UK    20
4    Jack    India   NaN
5   Nihal   Africa    30
6     Tom       UK    20
7     Tom       UK    20
8     Tom       UK    30
9     Tom       UK    20
10    Tom       UK    30
11    Sam       UK    30
12    Sam       UK    30
```

Comment: I need specifically Tom and Uk. and need to replace missing value only for these two. missing value should be mode of Tom and UK. As shown in the second excel.can you check that?

Comment: I've edited the answer to replace only Tom and UK

Comment: For multiple dot chaining, wrap all methods in parentheses (i.e., before `df` and after `reset_index`) and remove need of `\` at line breaks.

Comment: @99_m4n, hey if i want to drop the rows based on the same condition, how can i change it?

Comment: `df = df[(df.Name.ne('Tom') | df.location.ne('UK')) & df.Value.isna()]`